# How to create an index pattern in OpenSearch via API

Tags: opensearch

I have an OpenSearch custer running on-prem setup according to the [quickstart guide](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/quickstart/).
I managed to programatically add and query data via the API using PowerShell and cURL.
When I want to create an index pattern via API (works in the GUI) I get a "Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)"
I did that based on this [post...](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/how-to-create-index-pattern-through-dashboards-api/13928)
There seems to be no up-to-date documentation, only others describing similar problems but nothing helped. Any idea what else to try?

Code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$uri = "https://localhost:9200"
$username = "admin"
$password = "admin"
$credential = "${username}:${password}"
$credentialBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credential)
$base64Credential = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($credentialBytes)
$basicAuthHandler = "Basic $base64Credential"
$headers = @{
  Authorization=$basicAuthHandler
  "Content-Type"="application/x-ndjson"
}

$data = Get-Content -Path "bulk_projects.json" -Raw

# add sample data
try {
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/_bulk" -Method Post -Headers $headers -SkipCertificateCheck -Body $data
}
catch {
  echo "Error:"$_.Exception.Message
}

$response

# create index pattern

$indexPatternSpecification = @{
  attributes = @{
    title = "project*"
    timeFieldName = "@ProjectTimestamp"
  }
} | ConvertTo-Json

try {
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri/api/index_patterns/index-pattern/projects" -Method Post -Headers $headers -SkipCertificateCheck -Body $indexPatternSpecification
}
catch {
  echo "Error:"$_.Exception.Message
}

$response
```